# Prove a function is continuous?

Tags: calculus

$w(x)$ is positive and continuous in $N \cap \Omega$, $w(x) \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow \xi$. Let $B$ be a ball satisfying $\xi \in B \subset N$ and $
m= inf_{N-B} \omega(x)>0$.

Then **my question** is :how to prove the function $\overline w(x) = \left\{ 
  \begin{array}{l l}
    min(w, m) & \quad \text{if $x \in \overline \Omega \cap B$}\\
    m & \quad \text{if $x  \in \overline \Omega \backslash B$}
  \end{array} \right.$
is continuous. Especially the points on $\partial B$?

I think it is intuitively right. The points on $\partial B$ is $m$. The points near $\partial B$ and in $B$ is greater or equal to $m$. If the points there is $m$, then it is done. If the points in $B$ and near $\partial B$ is greater than $m$, then the value inside the $B$ will be $m$ until it is equal to $m$.

The above explanation is the best I can do. How to **prove it in a more convincing way like in terms of definition of continuous** instead of intuitive words?